# How do I fix Apple Mach-O Liker Error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit

I keep getting the Apple Mach-O Linker Error everytime I run my code with more than 3 scenes. I searched on this and  I tried doing what almost all the people said:
Product > Clean
Product > Clean Build Folder
Delete Derived Data
But none of them seemed to work in my case. I still get the error when I  build again.

Here's the complete error:

```
Ld /Users/rohankalantri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FinalTest(1)-actqlzklrbebyyfwvakdqnhcnozz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FinalTest(1).app/FinalTest(1) normal x86_64
    cd "/Volumes/MacData/xCode/FinalTest(1)/FinalTest(1)"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/rohankalantri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FinalTest(1)-actqlzklrbebyyfwvakdqnhcnozz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/rohankalantri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FinalTest(1)-actqlzklrbebyyfwvakdqnhcnozz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/rohankalantri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FinalTest(1)-actqlzklrbebyyfwvakdqnhcnozz/Build/Intermediates/FinalTest(1).build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FinalTest(1).build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FinalTest(1).LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/rohankalantri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FinalTest(1)-actqlzklrbebyyfwvakdqnhcnozz/Build/Intermediates/FinalTest(1).build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FinalTest(1).build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FinalTest(1)_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/rohankalantri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FinalTest(1)-actqlzklrbebyyfwvakdqnhcnozz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FinalTest(1).app/FinalTest(1)

duplicate symbol _level in:
    /Users/rohankalantri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FinalTest(1)-actqlzklrbebyyfwvakdqnhcnozz/Build/Intermediates/FinalTest(1).build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FinalTest(1).build/Objects-normal/x86_64/easyLevel.o
    /Users/rohankalantri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FinalTest(1)-actqlzklrbebyyfwvakdqnhcnozz/Build/Intermediates/FinalTest(1).build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FinalTest(1).build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mediumLevel.o
duplicate symbol _durationTime in:
    /Users/rohankalantri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FinalTest(1)-actqlzklrbebyyfwvakdqnhcnozz/Build/Intermediates/FinalTest(1).build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FinalTest(1).build/Objects-normal/x86_64/easyLevel.o
    /Users/rohankalantri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FinalTest(1)-actqlzklrbebyyfwvakdqnhcnozz/Build/Intermediates/FinalTest(1).build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FinalTest(1).build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mediumLevel.o
duplicate symbol _delayTime in:
    /Users/rohankalantri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FinalTest(1)-actqlzklrbebyyfwvakdqnhcnozz/Build/Intermediates/FinalTest(1).build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FinalTest(1).build/Objects-normal/x86_64/easyLevel.o
    /Users/rohankalantri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FinalTest(1)-actqlzklrbebyyfwvakdqnhcnozz/Build/Intermediates/FinalTest(1).build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FinalTest(1).build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mediumLevel.o
duplicate symbol _firstTime in:
    /Users/rohankalantri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FinalTest(1)-actqlzklrbebyyfwvakdqnhcnozz/Build/Intermediates/FinalTest(1).build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FinalTest(1).build/Objects-normal/x86_64/easyLevel.o
    /Users/rohankalantri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FinalTest(1)-actqlzklrbebyyfwvakdqnhcnozz/Build/Intermediates/FinalTest(1).build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FinalTest(1).build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mediumLevel.o
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And I also get this:
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Is there something I am doing wrong? How do I fix this issue?
PS: I am using Xcode 6 Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a) and Objective C.

Comment: What is the exact error message? I suggest searching for other similar questions because this kind of misconfiguration comes up often.

Comment: I did search other questions. And also tried what the answer had. But the error still pops up. It only comes when I have more than 3 scenes though. 

PS: The error I get is exactly the same as I have mentioned in the description of the question.

Comment: The error described in _the question you linked to_ is specific to Swift. You state that you are using Objective-C. We can’t help you if you don’t provide more information about your linker error. `Linker command failed with exit code 1` is insufficient. That linked question’s screenshot shows more output. Please copy/paste your output.

Comment: I have added the exact error in the description. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Thank you. For your next question starting off with as many error details as you can gather will save answerers and yourself time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds a bit like non-static global variables were declared in a header file and imported to both easyLevel and mediumLevel.

Comment: No, I am not creating any non static variables. I haven't made any changes to the .h file. It is just the way it was created.

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks  a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have class files for `easyLevel` and `mediumLevel`? It appears that they are being compiled multiple times and that this is causing your errors of `duplicate symbol`.

You can check this in Project Settings (top entry in your files list, named after your project) > Select Your Target in the list to the left > in the tab bar on top select “Build Phases” > “Compile Sources”. Then ensure each file source file is there only once.

You can see this with a screenshot in [Apple’s documentation “Controlling How an Individual File Is Compiled”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/Adding%20a%20Compiler%20Flag%20to%20a%20File.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH8-SW1)

Comment: Yup, each file source is only once and none is repeating.

Comment: Hmm. What do those easy and medium level classes do? Are they subclasses of sprite nodes?

Comment: Where do the symbols occur? Are they declared multiple times in one file or multiple times across multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when this happens to me, I find that I was importing an .m file instead of an .h file.

Comment: I am importing the .h files. Any other way this can be solved?